# Edit task workflow FORM change

Tags: workflow, share, alfresco, activiti

I have created my own custom workflow (for now this is just adhoc workflow customization) and i have managed to customize start workflow form, however a can not customize second form, this is edit task form (when user start process and assign to "someone", "someone" get task in inbox and he see edit task form). This second form is the same as my first plus some extra fields. This is because i need that "someone" can view and edit data entered on start workflow form. So i basically copied first form configuration to second form but this doesn't work, only sets and textareas are rendered. Anybody now how can i customize this?

workflow definition

```
<process id="appppV1" name="Proces otvaranja projekta">

<startEvent id="start" name="Start" activiti:formKey="mcwm:submitStart"></startEvent>

<userTask id="preparationOfProjectCharter" name="Priprema projektne povelje" activiti:assignee="${bpm_assignee.properties.userName}" activiti:formKey="mcwm:preparationOfProjectCharter">
  <extensionElements>
    <activiti:taskListener event="create" class="org.alfresco.repo.workflow.activiti.tasklistener.ScriptTaskListener">
      <activiti:field name="script">
        <activiti:string>if (typeof bpm_workflowDueDate != 'undefined') task.setVariableLocal('bpm_dueDate', bpm_workflowDueDate);</activiti:string>
      </activiti:field>
    </activiti:taskListener>
  </extensionElements>
</userTask>
```

model for workflow:

```
<types>
    <type name="mcwm:submitStart">
        <parent>bpm:startTask</parent>
        <properties>
            <property name="mcwm:projectName">
                <title>Naziv projekta</title>
                <type>d:text</type>
                <mandatory>true</mandatory>
            </property>
            <property name="mcwm:shortProjectName">
                <title>Skraćeni naziv projekta</title>
                <type>d:text</type>
                <mandatory>false</mandatory>
            </property>
            <property name="mcwm:projectOrderer">
                <title>Naručitelj projekta</title>
                <type>d:text</type>
                <mandatory>false</mandatory>
            </property>
            <property name="mcwm:shortProjectOrderer">
                <title>Skraćeni naziv naručitelja projekta</title>
                <type>d:text</type>
                <mandatory>false</mandatory>
            </property>
            <property name="mcwm:isoProcess">
                <title>ISO 9000 proces</title>
                <type>d:text</type>
                <mandatory>true</mandatory>
                <default> </default>
                <constraints>
                    <constraint name="mcwm:isoProcessChoices" type="LIST">
                        <parameter name="allowedValues">
                            <list>
                                <value> </value>
                                <value>održavanje - aplikativno</value>
                                <value>održavanje - sistemsko</value>
                                <value>konsalting</value>
                                <value>razvoj - sa odobrenjem arhitekture</value>
                                <value>razvoj - bez odobrenjem arhitekture</value>
                                <value>mali razvoj</value>
                                <value>implementacija</value>
                            </list>
                        </parameter>
                    </constraint>
                </constraints>
            </property>
            <property name="mcwm:reporting">
                <title>Učestalost izveštavanja</title>
                <type>d:text</type>
                <mandatory>true</mandatory>
                <default>mesečno</default>
                <constraints>
                    <constraint name="mcwm:reportingChoices" type="LIST">
                        <parameter name="allowedValues">
                            <list>
                                <value>mesečno</value>
                                <value>kvartalno</value>
                                <value>po okončanju</value>
                            </list>
                        </parameter>
                    </constraint>
                </constraints>
            </property>
            <property name="mcwm:projectGoals">
                <title>Ciljevi projekta</title>
                <type>d:text</type>
                <mandatory>false</mandatory>
            </property>

            <property name="mcwm:beginDate">
                <title>Datum početka projekta</title>
                <type>d:date</type>
                <mandatory>true</mandatory>
            </property>

            <property name="mcwm:endDate">
                <title>Datum okončanja projekta</title>
                <type>d:date</type>
                <mandatory>false</mandatory>
            </property>

            <property name="mcwm:team">
                <title>Projektni tim (*promena tipa kontorle)</title>
                <type>d:text</type>
                <mandatory>false</mandatory>
            </property>

            <property name="mcwm:teamResource">
                <title>Predviđeni utrošak ljudskih resursa (*promena tipa kontorle)</title>
                <type>d:text</type>
                <mandatory>false</mandatory>
            </property>

            <property name="mcwm:teamComent">
                <title>Komentar na predviđeni utrošak ljudskih resursa</title>
                <type>d:text</type>
                <mandatory>false</mandatory>
            </property>

            <property name="mcwm:changeComent">
                <title>Komentar izmene</title>
                <type>d:text</type>
                <mandatory>false</mandatory>
            </property>
        </properties>   
     <!--  To select a user -->
     <mandatory-aspects>
        <aspect>bpm:assignee</aspect>
     </mandatory-aspects>
    </type>

    <type name="mcwm:preparationOfProjectCharter">
        <parent>bpm:workflowTask</parent>
        <properties>
            <property name="mcwm:editTask">
                <title>Edit task</title>
                <type>d:text</type>
                <mandatory>true</mandatory>
            </property>
        </properties>
    </type>
```

share-config-custom.xml

```
<config evaluator="string-compare" condition="activiti$appppV1">
  <forms>
     <form>
        <field-visibility>
           <hide id="bpm:workflowDescription" />
           <hide id="bpm:workflowDueDate" />
           <hide id="bpm:workflowPriority" />
           <show id="bpm:assignee" />

           <show id="mcwm:projectName" />
           <show id="mcwm:shortProjectName" />
           <show id="mcwm:projectOrderer" />
           <show id="mcwm:shortProjectOrderer" />
           <show id="mcwm:isoProcess" />
           <show id="mcwm:reporting"/>
           <show id="mcwm:projectGoals"/>
           <show id="mcwm:beginDate"/>
           <show id="mcwm:endDate"/>

           <show id="mcwm:team"/>
           <show id="mcwm:teamResource"/>
           <show id="mcwm:teamComent"/>
           <show id="mcwm:changeComent"/>


           <hide id="packageItems" />
           <hide id="bpm:sendEMailNotifications" />
        </field-visibility>
        <appearance>
            <set id="" appearance="title" label-id="apppv1.set.projekat" />
            <set id="general" appearance="fieldset" label-id="appppV1.set.general" />
            <set id="date" template="/org/alfresco/components/form/2-column-set.ftl" appearance="fieldset" label-id="appppV1.set.date" />
            <set id="team" appearance="fieldset" label-id="appppV1.set.team" />
            <set id="change" appearance="fieldset" label-id="appppV1.set.change" />


           <field id="mcwm:projectName" set="general" />
           <field id="mcwm:shortProjectName" set="general" />
           <field id="mcwm:projectOrderer" set="general" />
           <field id="mcwm:shortProjectOrderer" set="general" />
           <field id="mcwm:isoProcess" set="general" />
           <field id="mcwm:reporting" set="general" />

           <field id="mcwm:projectGoals" set="general">
                <control template="/org/alfresco/components/form/controls/textarea.ftl">
                    <control-param name="style">width: 65%</control-param>
                    <control-param name="rows">5</control-param>
                </control>
            </field>

            <field id="mcwm:beginDate" set="date"/>
            <field id="mcwm:endDate" set="date"/>
            <field id="bpm:assignee" set="team" label="Voditelj projekta"/>
            <field id="mcwm:team" set="team">
                <control template="/org/alfresco/components/form/controls/textarea.ftl">
                    <control-param name="style">width: 65%</control-param>
                    <control-param name="rows">5</control-param>
                </control>
            </field>
            <field id="mcwm:teamResource" set="team"/>
            <field id="mcwm:teamComent" set="team">
                <control template="/org/alfresco/components/form/controls/textarea.ftl">
                    <control-param name="style">width: 65%</control-param>
                    <control-param name="rows">5</control-param>
                </control>
            </field>

            <field id="mcwm:changeComent" set="change">
                <control template="/org/alfresco/components/form/controls/textarea.ftl">
                    <control-param name="style">width: 65%</control-param>
                    <control-param name="rows">5</control-param>
                </control>
            </field>
        </appearance>
     </form>
  </forms>
```

share-config-custom.xml - second form

```
<config evaluator="task-type" condition="mcwm:preparationOfProjectCharter">
    <forms>
        <form>
            <field-visibility>
                <show id="mcwm:projectName"/>
                <show id="mcwm:editTask"/>
                <hide id="bpm:workflowDescription" />
                <hide id="bpm:workflowDueDate" />
                <hide id="bpm:workflowPriority" />
                <show id="bpm:assignee" />

                <show id="mcwm:projectName" />
                <show id="mcwm:shortProjectName" />
                <show id="mcwm:projectOrderer" />
                <show id="mcwm:shortProjectOrderer" />
                <show id="mcwm:isoProcess" />
                <show id="mcwm:reporting"/>
                <show id="mcwm:projectGoals"/>
                <show id="mcwm:beginDate"/>
                <show id="mcwm:endDate"/>

                <show id="mcwm:team"/>
                <show id="mcwm:teamResource"/>
                <show id="mcwm:teamComent"/>
                <show id="mcwm:changeComent"/>
             </field-visibility>
            <appearance>
                <set id="" appearance="title" label-id="apppv1.set.projekat" />
                <set id="general" appearance="fieldset" label-id="appppV1.set.general" />
                <set id="date" template="/org/alfresco/components/form/2-column-set.ftl" appearance="fieldset" label-id="appppV1.set.date" />
                <set id="team" appearance="fieldset" label-id="appppV1.set.team" />
                <set id="change" appearance="fieldset" label-id="appppV1.set.change" />


               <field id="mcwm:projectName" set="general" />
               <field id="mcwm:shortProjectName" set="general" />
               <field id="mcwm:projectOrderer" set="general" />
               <field id="mcwm:shortProjectOrderer" set="general" />
               <field id="mcwm:isoProcess" set="general" />
               <field id="mcwm:reporting" set="general" />

               <field id="mcwm:projectGoals" set="general">
                    <control template="/org/alfresco/components/form/controls/textarea.ftl">
                        <control-param name="style">width: 65%</control-param>
                        <control-param name="rows">5</control-param>
                    </control>
                </field>

                <field id="mcwm:beginDate" set="date"/>
                <field id="mcwm:endDate" set="date"/>
                <field id="bpm:assignee" set="team" label="Voditelj projekta"/>
                <field id="mcwm:team" set="team">
                    <control template="/org/alfresco/components/form/controls/textarea.ftl">
                        <control-param name="style">width: 65%</control-param>
                        <control-param name="rows">5</control-param>
                    </control>
                </field>
                <field id="mcwm:teamResource" set="team"/>
                <field id="mcwm:teamComent" set="team">
                    <control template="/org/alfresco/components/form/controls/textarea.ftl">
                        <control-param name="style">width: 65%</control-param>
                        <control-param name="rows">5</control-param>
                    </control>
                </field>

                <field id="mcwm:changeComent" set="change">
                    <control template="/org/alfresco/components/form/controls/textarea.ftl">
                        <control-param name="style">width: 65%</control-param>
                        <control-param name="rows">5</control-param>
                    </control>
                </field>
                <field id="mcwm:editTask" set="general" read-only="true"/>
            </appearance>
        </form>
    </forms>
```

I try to use in show tag with force="true" attribute and this show my filed but data aren't transfered from my start from?!

Thanks in advance for help.

Regards,
Aleksandar

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that you are not seeing any fields because *mcwm:preparationOfProjectCharter* task has no properties that you are trying to display.

If you want the same properties on second task that you have on first task you will have to define them in your task model.

If the properties are exactly the same and repeating  a lot, you can specify them as an aspect and add them as mandatory aspect in task model.

Comment: Hi, me again. :) Solution which i described above works but a have to put explicitly task property on process, and those properties are exactly the same and repeating (every task in process has them) so i decided to define custom aspect and add them as mandatory as you described. That's ok with one minor problem. In my aspect i have i.e three properties, all are mandatory. On my second task i add that aspect and i want to set aspect properties mandatory to false, i use override property tags but this isn't functioning, is this possible anyway?

Comment: Where do you use override tag?

Comment: In model of my second task. I add aspect as mandatory on first and second task. By default property of aspect are set as mandatory, and that's ok for my first task, but i want on second task to set those properties to mandatory=false. I use in second task model
<overrides>
   <property name="mcwm:projectName">
      <mandatory>false</mandatory>
   </property>
but this has no effect.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for your help. :) I done something quite similar. I just set on my second task that parent is first task

```
<type name="mcwm:preparationOfProjectCharter">
<parent>mcwm:submitStart</parent>
```

and now i have all property from first task on my second task.

Regards,

Aleksandar

Comment: For now works for me :). I am using Alfresco Enterprise Edition 4.0.